# Unknown column error

Tags: mysql

I guess it is a really simple thing, but i cannot find a way to solve. Here is my query;

```
SELECT A.*,MAX(A.id) as X
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON(B.id=A.id)
WHERE B.y > IF(X < 75, 0, 100)
```

mysql rises an error saying that column 'X' is unknown. I do not want to replace 'X' in if clause with `SELECT MAX(A.id) from A`, because it dramatically slows down the query, since I think it queries `SELECT MAX(A.id) from A` for every value comparison between `B.y`. If this kind of approach is not possible which I do not really expect, then I have to call two distinct queries first getting the max scalar value, then putting it into the query above. I wonder whether it can be solved in a single query.

Similar question is asked but it does not seem to be solved yet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052196/mysql-error-1054-unknown-column-on-clause

Is it related with scopes or something similar?

Comment: Please elaborate a little more (preferably in your question) on what you are trying to do. That might help in finding a proper solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in the `WHERE` clause. You will need to use the full expression, or use HAVING instead. I would try both and see which one provides the best performances.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*,MAX(A.id) as X
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON(B.id=A.id)
HAVING B.y > IF(MAX(A.id) < 75, 0, 100)
```

@andryi-m was right. The query didn't even compile.

**EDIT:** Below is a quite ugly solution, but I think it will work. Pretty sure it can be improved:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON(B.id=A.id)
WHERE B.y > IF((SELECT MAX(A.id) FROM A INNER JOIN B ON (B.id=A.id)) < 75, 0, 100)
```

I'm repeating the first query in the `WHERE` clause to get the highest `id` only on matches between tables `A` and `B`.

Comment: please try an explain what ever you do

Comment: This [won't compile](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0fc5/1). HAVING can't reference columns that are neither aggregated nor in the GROUP BY. And since there's no *explicit* GROUP BY, HAVING can reference no non-aggregated column (from either `A` or `B`) at all.

Comment: @andriy-m: Yeah, you're right. It was too easy to be true. Working on it.

Comment: andriy is right, your query did not compile. B.y is unknown column in this case.